# How can we use multiple processes in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, c, multiprocessing, fortran, fork

I am trying to execute 16 tasks assigned one by one to each element of an array called `tasks_ready_master`. I want to avoid using OMP Tasking.
I thought about using the fork/wait method.

```
!$OMP SINGLE 
       n=16
       do ff =1,n
          pid=c_fork()
          if (pid < 0) then
             call perror('fork()' // c_null_char)
          else if  (pid == 0) then
             call tasks_ready_master(ff+4)%f_ptr(self,var)
             call exit(STATUS)
          else
             pid=c_wait(STATUS)
             call sleep(50)
          end if
       end do
!$OMP END SINGLE
```

I referred to the C code I found on [Multiple child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876605/multiple-child-process).
For the `unix` module, I followed the steps on https://cyber.dabamos.de/programming/modernfortran/fork.html.

The idea is to create 16 child processes and each process will execute a task.
From what I understood, the code under `else if  (pid == 0) then` is executed by a child process.

I don't understand the `c_wait` function and is it necessary to use the `sleep` function here ?

For me the part under `else` (parent process) is useless. Is it important ? Without it, It shows me:

```
fork(): Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Sorry but there isn't no enough documentation on fork/wait in Fortran.

(I will tag C since one of the links I posted (in my question) contains a C code and the functions used are from C.)

Thanks to the comments, I have:

```
       n=3
       do ff =1,n
          pid(ff)=c_fork()
          if (pid(ff) < 0) then
             call perror('fork()' // c_null_char)
          else if  (pid(ff) == 0) then
             call tasks_ready_master(ff+4)%f_ptr(self,var)
             call exit(STATUS)
          end if
       end do

       do ff=1,n
          pid(ff)=c_wait(STATUS)
       end do
```

I consider `pid` as an array of 16 integer elements.

Comment: `Resource temporarily unavailable` could mean that you've tried to spawn more processes than you are allowed to spawn.  Yes, the code in the `if (pid == 0) then` block is where the child processes will run. Your code does however seem to only spawn 1 child at a time and wait for it to finish which makes the execution of the 16 processes done in a serial fashion - with a `sleep(50)` after each.

Comment: Do you want to run all child processes concurrently or one after the other? The `wait_c` in the loop would wait for the end of the process (more precisely for a status change) in the parent process before starting the next child. To run the children concurrently you would have to call `wait_c` (or an alternative function) at the end of the parent process or when you want to react on a child's status change. Normally, the `sleep` should not be necessary. WIth 16 child processes I would not expect `fork` to fail with `Resource temporarily unavailable`. Probably you have more child processes.

Comment: @Bodo Can you check my question please (I edited it) and tell me if I really understood what you said in your comment ? I get the `Resource temporarily unavailable` only when I retire the `c_wait` call. I want to run all child processes concurrently. Is the right place where to call `c_wait` ? Thanks for your help ! I also changed pid from an integer to an array of integers.

Comment: @hakim Please [edit] your question and add all requested information or clarification there. The 2nd variant looks more reasonable. Your 1st loop will continue if one `c_fork` reports an error and store the resulting value `-1` in the `pid` array. I don't know if this is what you need/want. In the 2nd loop it doesn't make sense to overwrite the `pid` array with the return value of `c_wait`. You have to call wait once for every child you started. `wait` will return -1 and set `errno` to `ECHILD` if there is no (more) child process to wait for. Do you still get errors with the new program?

Comment: @Bodo my problem with `wait` in Fortran is that it's a function not like in C where it is a subroutine.  And I'm not sure if the equivalent of `wait` is `c_wait` in Fortran. There is not enough documentation on this topic. I wrote  `pid(ff)=c_wait(STATUS)` because I didn't know how to use `c_wait` here as a function.. Okay I'll edit my question in order to provide more details.

Comment: You can assign the return value of `c_wait` to a simple variable and use the value to check for an error report (value < 0). No need to assign it to the array. You could check if a positive return value of `c_wait` matches any of the PIDs stored in the array to find out whoch child exited, but I don't think this is necessary in your case. I guess it is not even necessary to keep an array of all PIDs returned by `c_fork`. (It was about 35 years ago when I last used Fortran on a computer that filled half a room, built of discrete components instead of integrated circuits.)